# Dynamics CRM Map Chart no map Charts

Tags: charts, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

In Chart map Config , there are no default map charts, and when i create a new one i can only create pie, line, bar etc charts.

I am using this ;
[Dynamic CRM Map Chart](https://crmmapchart.codeplex.com/discussions)

Should there be an option to create a map chart?
Is there a good tutorial on how to do this.

Can someone help me with this , please. 
Point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM charts dont support maps out of the box.

The only maps you can you use out the of the box are Bing Maps for specific addresses, and even this requires setup. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/10/22/enhanced-bing-maps-experience-in-crm-2013.aspx

What you have linked to is a third party add-on, so you are best speaking to them if you want to know how it works.